# How many base elements can a sunflower-free system have?

Tags: co.combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics, extremal-set-theory

A collection of $t$ sets $A_i$ is called a **t-sunflower** if $A_i \cap A_j = Z $ for all $i \neq j$ for some fixed $Z$. A well-known conjecture of Erdős and Rado says that there is a constant $C_t$ such that in any $k$-uniform family of size at least $C_t^k$ there is a $t$-sunflower. This is still wide open even for $t=3$; for more, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunflower_(mathematics).

> But what can we say about the base set of a $t$-sunflower-free $k$-uniform family?

Of course, we can add arbitrarily many elements that are not contained in any set, so I'm only counting elements that are contained in at least one set. In other words, I'm looking for an upper bound for the size of the union of the sets. The number of base elements is at most $k$ times the number of the sets, but maybe there is a way to prove without using the Erdős-Rado conjecture that there can be at most $C_t^k$ elements in the base set. This question first appeared in our [recent preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.16701).

Comment: What is a base?

Comment: The union of the sets from the family.

Comment: Can’t I just fix an extremal construction of uniformity $k-1$, and then add a unique ”dummy element” for each edge?

Comment: I wonder how the hell we missed that... Would you convert this into an answer?

Comment: meanwhile, I'm wondering how I missed Conjecture 14 (since I definitely looked at this preprint of yours)

Comment: This is great! If the OP updates his recent preprint with content from this MO thread, then it might be a good one to advertise on https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/617/best-of-mathoverflow-or-papers-inspired-by-mathoverflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, this is not an easier question. Indeed, one can start with a maximal $t$-sunflower-free collection in uniformity $k-1$, and then add a unique "dummy element" to each edge in this construction. Thus, your problem has a bound of $\exp(O_t(k))$ if and only if the original Erdos-Rado problem has a bound of $\exp(O_t(k))$.

Here's an attempt to propose a new question in the spirit you intended:

> Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a $k$-uniform $t$-sunflower-free family. Is there
> some vertex that is contained in at least $c_t^k|\mathcal{H}|$ of the
> edges (where $c_t>0$ is some absolute constant)?

EDIT: my question is also silly. If no element is contained by a $(1/tk)$-fraction of the edges from $\mathcal{H}$, then we can greedily find $t$ disjoint sets.

Comment: See, it's not so easy to ask these questions ;)

Comment: my eyes have been opened.